# Azure cli behind corporate proxy not working (SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER)

Tags: ssl, proxy, azure-cli

I have my `C:\\Users\\xxxx\\cacert-with-corp-proxy-cert.pem` file updated with corporate ssl proxy certificate. To confirm that pem file updated properly and corporate proxy ssl certificates are valid, I performed the check with `python.exe (Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\python.exe)`:

```
import urllib.request
import ssl
import certifi
import requests
url = "https://www.google.com/"
```

This one works:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ssl.create_default_context(
       cafile="C:\\Users\\xxxx\\cacert-with-corp-proxy-cert.pem"))
```

This one doesn't work (as expected):

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url,context=ssl.create_default_context(
       cafile="C:\\Users\\xxxx\\cacert-default.pem"))
```

But, when I am trying to use **REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE="C:\Users\xxxx\cacert-with-corp-proxy-cert.pem"** with **az login** command I see the following error:

> Certificate verification failed. This typically happens when using Azure CLI behind a proxy that intercepts traffic with a self-signed certificate. Please add this certificate to the trusted CA bundle. More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/use-cli-effectively#work-behind-a-proxy. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='login.microsoftonline.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /common/oauth2/token (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1125)')))

value of the **REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE** environment variable is picked up correctly by *az login* command (tested with dummy file link and it gives *"file not found"* error)

*The rest of params:*

```
PS C:\Users\xxxx> $env:SSL_CERT_FILE
C:\Users\xxxx\cacert-with-corp-proxy-cert.pem

PS C:\Users\xxxx> $env:REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE
C:\Users\xxxx\cacert-with-corp-proxy-cert.pem

PS C:\Users\xxxx> az version
{
  "azure-cli": "2.29.0",
  "azure-cli-core": "2.29.0",
  "azure-cli-telemetry": "1.0.6",
  "extensions": {}
}

PS C:\Users\xxxx> $env:HTTP_PROXY
http://gate-xxx.xxxxxx.com:8080

PS C:\Users\xxxx> $env:HTTPS_PROXY
https://gate-xxx.xxxxxx.com:9443
```

Comment: The error WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER has nothing to do with certificate validation. Claiming to be a certificate validation problem is the wrong interpretation. This error is instead common when trying to access a proxy by https which does not speak https. Do you really have a different proxy for HTTP and HTTPS? - this is kind of unusual.

Comment: Yes, we do have different proxies for http and https (same host, different ports). The https proxy accessed via https protocol *sorry, it was a typo in my question, now updated the rest of params block to https)

Comment: the urllib.request.getproxies() command retreive and use them successfully: 
{'https': 'https://gate-xxx.xxxxxx:9443', 'http': 'http://gate-xxx.xxxxxx.com:8080'}

Comment: Setting of HTTPS_PROXY="http://gate-xxx.xxxxxx.com:8080" solved the problem